# ddslick not work together another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML code ;

```
<select class="gonderimsekli">
          <option value="0" data-imagesrc="images/tekyon.png" data-description="Kurye yönlendirilen adresten teslimat adresine gider." selected="selected" >Tek Yön</option>
          <option value="777" data-description="Kurye yönlendirilen adrese gelir, teslimat adresine gider , tekrar yönlendirilen adrese teslimat yapar." data-imagesrc="images/ciftyon.png">Gidiş - Dönüş</option>

        </select>
```

This is my ddslick object

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                 $('.gonderimsekli').dclick({                    
                         onSelected: function(data){
                       $('.ddc-selected-value').prop ('name', 'donus');
                      var input = $("input[name=donus]").val(); 
                      var yon=ciftyon;
                     if(input==777) {   gidisdonus(input,yon); }
                     else
                     {  gidisdonus(input,yon); } }});
</script>
```

this is my ddslick object function.

But it is not working with the `gidisdonus` function.

and this `gidisdonus`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function gidisdonus(id2,id){
         var select = id2;  
         if(select>0) {
             document.getElementById(id).className="gorunur";
             document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
         } else {
             document.getElementById(id).className="gorunmez";
             document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
         }
    }
-->
</script>
```

The `ciftyon` id is `<tr id="ciftyon"><td></td></tr>`

End result:
gorunmez - class >> "display:none"

Comment: What is `dclick`? Do you mean `ddslick`?

Comment: yes ddslick. i changed it becasuse i have got 3 units. 1. ddslick 2.dslick 3.dclick.  When the same name conflicts

Comment: I can't think of why that would be necessary, but I don't know this library. Good luck!